# Global variable wont update in second variable

Tags: javascript, scope

When I call `foo2`,  the global variable `divFoo` wont update when I `console.log` it.

```
var foo = 0;
var divFoo = "<div id='"+foo+"'>"
var foo2 = function() {
    foo++
}
```

I have seen other questions pertaining to this issue and I felt that those didn't fully answer why this happens. `divFoo` shows div id='0' when `foo` is counting up. How do I make divFoo count up with foo?

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope. `"<div id='"+foo+"'>"` creates a new string that has no link at all to the `foo` variable. If you want `divFoo` to change then you'd need to put `divFoo = "<div id='"+foo+"'>"` inside the `foo2()` function body. Or instead of a `divFoo` variable, create a function `divFoo()` that returns `"<div id='"+foo+"'>"`.

Comment: Ok, I was assuming that it would update it in real time. Thanks!

Comment: If you want this to happen "automatically", look at one of the "reactive" frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `divFoo` when you update `foo`. It doesn't listen for changes, it's static.

Like this:

```
var foo = 0;
var divFoo;
var foo2 = function() {
    foo++;
    divFoo = "<div id='"+foo+"'>";
}
```

Comment: Or perhaps if the OP wants to save a line, they could put this in `foo2`: `divFoo = "<div id='" + (++foo) + "'>"`.

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld oh absolutely! I just wanted it to be clear that's all.